# Plots with many data points in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plot

I am building a dashboard using JS, that will show users plots of their sales data. Can you suggest a js library, which:

1. Can plot many points (100k for instance or even more)
2. Interactive
3. Supports SSR without losing interactivity (if it’s possible. I just assume that the only way to load this number of data without hurting UX is SSR)
4. Optional: works with React

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: I uses [chartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/) for charts. I think there will be a wrapper for react too.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably many options but one could be [Victory Chart](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-chart). The library is built on top of D3.js and is heavily customizable. For your large dataset, I can think of one solution I used that is documented [here](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/guides/zoom-large-data/).
One reason I'd suggest Victory is because they have a nice support community [here](https://gitter.im/FormidableLabs/victory).

I read many blog posts about that topic, [here's one](https://blog.sicara.com/compare-best-javascript-chart-libraries-2017-89fbe8cb112d) that compares a few "big" chart libraries with React Components.

For time series, I'd suggest having a look at [this](https://github.com/esnet/react-timeseries-charts) library.

If nothing works with large datasets, I think that your best option would be D3.js (with or without a React implementation).

Comment: thanks. Continuously loading data seems an attractive solution.
I am wondering if it is possible to pre-render a plot and store it as a plain HTML string on my backend (I read in plotly docs, that HTML pre-render is possible). And, once required, inject it into the react app. Have you heard of something similar? Do you think it might work?

Comment: I'll be honest, I have not experienced any sort of server rendering with react and totally forgot about your bullet point n°3. I've read some blog about d3.js with SSR but that's about it. Sorry.